# Port forwarding from ec2 to local pc

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, debugging, ssh

i uploaded my web application to aws ec2. now i want to be able to debug the application while she is running on the cloud. to be able to do that i want to  make ssh port forwarding from port 9229 that is responsible for google chrome dev tools debugger to port 9229 on my personal pc, so i be will able to debug the ec2 via my pc.

to connect to ssh and create port forwarding i run:
ssh -i "name-of-file.pem"  -L 9229:localhost:9229 ubuntu@ec2-3-91-90-243.ec2name.amazonaws.com

but when i enter to chrome://inspect/#devices i see no device available under remote target.

so does i make the connection and the port forwarding wrong, or i need to do something additional to be able to connect to the debugger of ec2 from my local pc?

Comment: also if im typing http://localhost:9229/ in the browser on the local pc the result is:This site can’t be reached

Comment: Maybe obvious: on the remote ec2 machine check if debugging is on, and on port 9229.

Comment: yes, in the ec2 im activating the option by node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 index.

Comment: Presume you can SSH to the EC2 instance just fine, yes?

Comment: That port forwarding command looks correct. You can verify that there's something listening at the other end (assuming you're on Linux) with `cat < /dev/tcp/localhost/9229`. If nothing's listening, you'll get a "connection refused" message. If there is, you might see a "banner" message, or you might see nothing (in which case, Ctrl-C to break the connection).

Comment: It's possible that the debugger (I'm assuming you're running Node on the server) will try to open a port back out to the client., and that's what's actually failing. I don't know if that's the case, but it's worth reading the docs closely; maybe there's even a doc for remote debugging.